# Powershell download file not working properly

Tags: exception, powershell, download

I am trying to write a powershell script that will set a download directory variable based on the current directory, and download a file to that directory.

The code I have is:

```
cd downloads
$DevDownloadDirectory = [IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory

$clnt = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

# download and extract the file
$url = “fileurl/file.zip"
$file = "$DevDownloadDirectory\file.zip"
$clnt.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

The problem I get is whenever I get to this part of the code it pumps out:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception
>   occurred during a WebClient request." At C:\directory\script.ps1:462
>   char:20
>
> - $clnt.DownloadFile <<<< ($url,$file)
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Could anyone please help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Any help here? http://stillpearling.blogspot.com/2009/02/more-powershell-adventures.html

Comment: Watch out for the incorrect quotation-symbol on the line: `$url = "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$DevDownloadDirectory = [IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory
```

Should be

```
$DevDownloadDirectory = [IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
```

GetCurrentDirectory() is a Method and if you dont use the "()", it will just return the same name but not the current directory.

Comment: It should also be noted that GetCurrentDirectory() will return the working directory of PowerShell, not your current directory.  Unless you update it yourself.  You should use $pwd instead.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I should note that I used what Jason suggested for $pwd so that I can get the working directory to be the variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Dowload File
function Download-File-Func($url, $targetFile)
{
    "Downloading $url"
    $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"
    $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $request.set_Timeout(600000) #10 minutes
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024)
    $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create
    $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB
    $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
    $downloadedBytes = $count
    while ($count -gt 0)
        {
        [System.Console]::CursorLeft = 0
        [System.Console]::Write("Downloaded {0}K of {1}K", [System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024), $totalLength)
        $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
        $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
        $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count
    }

    "Finished Download"
    $targetStream.Flush()
    $targetStream.Close()
    $targetStream.Dispose()
    $responseStream.Dispose()
}
```